# Is there a way to display WPF Extended Toolkit's control in VS Designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, visual-studio-designer

I'm used to create my forms with the designer, and modifying the XAML manually only when needed.

Even though the extended toolkit is a fantastic library, it still lacks integration with Visual Studio's designer. Can, by any mean, the toolkit's controls be displayed in the **designer** (not the toolbox), like standard controls? And if not, is there an explanation?

For now, the toolkit's controls are just blank and unselectable with simple clicks.

NOTE: It seems that the issue happens with container components (like BusyIndicator and Wizard/WizardPage) only.

EDIT: Here's some of my XAML. With this, I can see the wizard's first page, but no obvious way to see the others. If I put my Wizard in a BusyIndicator, can't see a thing at all.

```
<Window x:Class="MyProgram.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProgram"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="My Program" Height="477" Width="688" MinWidth="688" MinHeight="478">
    <xctk:Wizard x:Name="wizard" FinishButtonClosesWindow="True" Next="wizard_Next">
        <xctk:WizardPage Name="Intro_Page"  Title="ABC" Description="abc" NextPage="{Binding ElementName=Second_Page}" Enter="disallowNext">
            <xctk:WizardPage.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Content="abc" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,54,0,87" Name="intro_lbl" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Padding="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="28" IsEnabled="False" />
                 </Grid>
            </xctk:WizardPage.Content>
        </xctk:WizardPage>
        <xctk:WizardPage Name="Second_Page" Title="DFG" Description="dfg" NextPage="{Binding ElementName=Last_Page}">
            <xctk:WizardPage.Content>
                <Grid Name="grid">
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="txt_second" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </xctk:WizardPage.Content>
        </xctk:WizardPage>
        <xctk:WizardPage Name="Last_Page" PageType="Interior"
                         Title="Last Page"
                         Description="This is the last page in the process"
                         CanFinish="True" />
    </xctk:Wizard>
</Window>
```

Comment: I know I've seen them display for me in the past, but I don't know enough about your setup to comment on why they wouldn't be showing for you.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to add controls to the form by designer? All controls, even from other libraries must be in toolbox.

Comment: @Vitaliy No, I know how to get the controls to show up in the toolbox. I want them to actually have a display inside the designer window, instead of being completely blank and unselectable by click.

Comment: @Kilazur hmm, they must display without some actions... I think there is some problem with this library

Comment: @Vitaliy Well, if you have an example of another third party WPF library from which visual studio's designer manage to display controls, I'd like to check it out, just to know.

Comment: You can try wpf toolkit

Comment: Show us your xaml! WPF Toolkit and the extension right? We've been using them for a long time, but it's hard to tell with no xaml :) The BusyIndicator is actually a bit annoying, because you have to comment it out or you will be unable to click other things in the designer. Is this by chance an xbap fulltrust applciation(bleh! ;) )? Back in the days we had to manually sign the assemblies, but I think they fixed that along time ago. You should have received some security exception in that case. Nuget? Codeplex?

Comment: @Stian added XAML. I got the toolkit from Codeplex.

Comment: @Kilazur I duplicated your project, and I have the same behaviour here, I have never used those pages before. This even got the assembly through nuget. Never used those controls before, though I've used tons of others. So no dice! I suggest you ask your question here wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/create. Works all well when running, but not in the designer. Usually I create one file and one viewmodel for each page, though I am not using WizardPage. Alternatively you can bind them through the ItemsSource property.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer comes late, but yesterday I was stumbling myself over this problem and maybe it is useful for others who land here.

I solved it by creating an own control derived from `WizardPage`.
Just Create a new `UserControl`, include the Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit namespace and change the Type from `UserControl` to `xctk:WizardPage` in the xaml file as well as in the code-behind file.

```
<xctk:WizardPage x:Class="WizardTest.MyWizardPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:xctk="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WizardTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock>Hello World!</TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</xctk:WizardPage>
```

Now you can create your UI using the VisualStudio Designer.
To place your page in the wizard, simply put an object of you derived page into its items:

```
<xctk:Wizard>
  <local:MyWizardPage Title="My Wizard Page"/>
</xctk:Wizard>
```

You can use `Bindungs` in your costum page out of the box because `DataContext` of the `MyWizardPage` object is set automatically to the wizards `DataContext` (which inherits from the Window `DataContext` if not explicitly given)